# Executing for loop in Bash with csv and download file on internet

Tags: bash, for-loop, terminal, download

So for my thesis I want to download climate weather data from the Canadian government. They have provided me with a command that allows me to download all data for a specific weather station:

```
for year in `seq 1998 2008`;do for month in `seq 1 1`;do wget --content-disposition "https://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_data/bulk_data_e.html?format=csv&stationID=1706&Year=${year}&Month=${month}&Day=14&timeframe=2&submit= Download+Data" ;done;done
```

However, I want to create a forloop for this, so that it automatically downloads the data for all required weather stations. I have created a csv file with all necessary StationIDs, which is called: *stations.csv*

So far I have:

```
while read line \
do \
echo ... \
done < stations.csv
```

However, when I copy-paste the code and change 1706 (which is a stationID) to $line it does not work. Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: what are you using as your download utility... `wget`?... I will post an answer that will give you a start.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `wget`, maybe:

```
wget -i stations.csv
```

or

```
while read line; do
  echo ${line}
  wget ${line}
done < stations.csv
```

Comment: I don't know if the echo ${line} also contributed to me having fixed it, but I learned about 'Carriage Return Line Feed'. Seeing that each ${line} input received an %0D after the line-value, I googled for it. I found out that I accidentatily (didnt know about it making a difference) saved the .txt file with CRLF rather than solely LF (i'm on mac). That made the difference and now it works! Anyway, thanks for taking the time to help me!

Answer (score 0):

For people who are facing the same issue. Make sure that you check your .txt-file settings. If you are on windows, use CRLF; mac-users, use LF.

The final code:

```
> tail +2 stations.txt | while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
> echo ${line}; for year in `seq 1998 2008`;do for month in `seq 1 1`;do
> wget --content-disposition
> "https://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_data/bulk_data_e.html?format=csv&stationID=${line}&Year=${year}&Month=${month}&Day=14&timeframe=2&submit=
> Download+Data" ;done; done; sleep 2; done
```

*Document name:* stations. txt 
*Document header:* tail +2 -> starting the loop from the second row.
*Sleep setting:* This reduces strain on website by waiting inbetween loops.